# is there a a "particular solution" to these kind of first order differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have had this case various times, where the homogeneous solution contains no 'e'. Which means it is not the standard form. If i am correct the homogeneous solution of a first order differential equation should always contain a 'e'.

Now regarding to the two following cases:

1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYWir.jpg

2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNuPj.jpg

Is there a particular solution?
The solution to the equations (which is different from mine):

1) $ y(x) = C tg (t/2) $

2) $ y(x) = C(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) $

Did I make a mistake or is there another way to make my solution the same as the expected one?

Comment: Please avoid regarding links in your question and try to write them down! :)

Comment: In 2, after a while you had $\ln(y|)=\ln(|x^3+x^2+x+1|)+C$. When you exponentiate, you should get $|y|=e^C|x^3+x^2+x+1|$, and when you take off the absolute values, $y=K(x^3+x^2+x+1)$.  There is no issue about the lackof "$e$," since after the integration you had logs on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 
$$ \ln|y| = -\ln|\cot t + \csc t| + c_1 $$

Taking the exponential of this gives
$$ y = e^{-\ln|\cot t + \csc t|+c_1} $$
$$ y = e^{c_1} |\cot t + \csc t|^{-1} $$
$$ y = \pm e^{c_1}(\cot t + \csc t)^{-1} $$

$\pm e^{c_1}$ is just another constant, so
$$ y = \frac{C}{\cot t + \csc t} $$

To make it look like the given solution, just multiply by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}$
$$ y = \frac{C\sin t}{\cos t + 1} $$
$$ y = \frac{2C\sin \frac{t}{2} \cos \frac{t}{2}}{2\cos^2 \frac{t}{2}} $$
$$ y = \frac{C\sin \frac{t}{2}}{\cos \frac{t}{2}} = C\tan \frac{t}{2}$$

2) 
$$ \ln|y| = \ln|x^3 + x^2 + x + 1| + c_1 $$

Same as (1), taking the exponential of both sides gives you
$$ y = C(x^3 + x^2 + x + 1) $$

To answer your initial question, the solution is in the exponential form $y = e^{rt}$ only if it has constant coefficients
$$ ay' + by = 0 $$
In the above cases, the coefficients are functions of $t$, so the solution is not in that form